# What is a Wildcard for TLS edge routing in openshift

Tags: routes, openshift, wildcard

i asked someone how to use TLS in my project and he told me he will create a wildcard for my project, where i only have to activate the edge on the route?
but i did not understood what he mean by that?

ps: I am working on a project in openshift cluster (local crc) and using route objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your local OpenShift CRC environment is related to someone else creating a wildcard TLS certificate for you, but here is the basic idea.

Namespaces and applications in OpenShift can be created dynamically and on-the-fly. That means we'll need to be able to route traffic into our cluster without knowing what the application name or namespace will be.

To do that, users usually create a DNS entry for `*.apps.example.com` that they will then point to the OpenShift cluster. In our cluster, we then create a `Route` for the host `myexample`. So when someone queries `myexample.apps.example.com`, this traffic will be directed to the OpenShift cluster (specifically to the [OpenShift Ingress / Router](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/ingress-operator.html)). The Ingress / Router then forwards the traffic to the application.

For TLS, users typically [configure a default ingress certificate](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/security/certificates/replacing-default-ingress-certificate.html). This is the certificate that is served when a route ("myexample.apps.example.com") is called with TLS ("https://"). So that certificate is often called the "wildcard certificate".

Other options (if you do not want to use the default certificate for the cluster) is to use [edge or re-encrypt](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/routes/secured-routes.html) Routes.

Comment: Thanks alot! But what you mean with "myexample" in your example "myexample.apps.example.com" is it the name of a route object?

Comment: I clarified the answer above. Yes, that would be the "host" specified in the Route object